# Ajax file upload

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, file-upload, upload

I want to upload a file using Ajax and php. I have a form with `<input type="file">` tag. I want when user browses a file and clicks on submit, the file to be uploaded without a refresh. How should I do this ? It does't matter if refresh occur but i want to upload file with help of ajax.

Comment: I wonder what "file inclusion tag" is? I'm guessing it doesn't work, but interesting term/idea.

Comment: I think he wanted to say <input type="file"> with words :))

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320069/jquery-ajax-file-upload

Comment: You can use only javascript to do it, here's [complete code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27602218/2835520)

Answer (score 8):

- Use a hidden iframe and set your form's target to that iframe's name.  This way, when the form is submitted, only the iframe will be refreshed.
- Have an event handler registered for the iframe's load event to parse the response.

More details on my blog post: http://blog.manki.in/2011/08/ajax-fie-upload.html

Answer (score 2):

I did it with this jquery plugin. It pretty much mimics standard jquery ajax functionality, but also allows you to send data using iframe. No flash involved, pure javascript.

http://malsup.com/jquery/form/

Here is a file upload example
http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#file-upload

Answer (score 1):

This plugin uses XHR for uploading multiple files with progress-bar in FF3.6+, Safari4+, Chrome and falls back to hidden iframe based upload in other browsers, providing good user experience everywhere.
check this:
http://valums.com/ajax-upload/

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [SWFUpload](http://www.swfupload.org/), it should do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Here some I found http://blog.insicdesigns.com/2010/02/10-best-ajax-file-uploader-for-your-web-application/
 and also   [jquery upload](http://www.webdeveloperjuice.com/2010/02/13/7-trusted-ajax-file-upload-plugins-using-jquery/)
plugins