# Best way to make an ajax uploading file?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I want make an uploading system with ajax [none page reload]

I have search on google, found some thing, upload in `iframes` , `File API` etc...

Old browsers havent file API, and I have some problems with `iFrame` uploading in `IE` ,

Is there any way to make it with working in all browsers?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8400488/how-to-submit-file-upload-form-with-ajax?rq=1

Comment: Please see the solution provided in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously-with-jquery

Comment: thats using File API?! Only HTML5 supports , want some thing like iframe uploading...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ajax file upload](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2751795/ajax-file-upload)

Answer (score 1):

Since your tags include [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery), I would suggest that the best solution for you would be the [jQuery Form Plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/).

This plugin makes it very easy to work with forms via ajax, including forms with file upload fields. You don't need to worry about the browser API or whether it supports it or not; the plugin deals with all that behind the scenes.

There are good examples on the plugin's website, and I can confirm it works well as I've just implemented it in a project myself.

Hope that helps.

Comment: @user1714757 - there are excellent examples on the site I linked. I couldn't provide anything better than that.

Comment: if im using the plugin , the older browsers do what i want?

Comment: I answered that already. But to confirm: As stated on the plugin site: `For older browsers, a fallback technology is used which involves iframes`. So the answer is **yes, it works with older browsers.**

Comment: also, the demos and examples are there on the site, so you could have found out the answer just by trying the demos in an old browser for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Use Uploadify. It's really simple and looks great.

http://www.uploadify.com/

Comment: Good luck. You'll be hard pressed to solicit code here. This is not a charity website.