# Display image after clicking upload

Tags: php

How to display images right after they clicked the upload button?

Here is my HTML Code:

form.php

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="uploadFile.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label for="file">Filename:</label>
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

And here is my uploadFile.php code:(updated, but still not getting any result)

```
<?php
       // prevent timezone warnings
       date_default_timezone_set('Philippines/Manila');

      // set the upload location
      $UPLOADDIR = "images/";

        // if the form has been submitted then save and display the image(s)
    if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){
      // loop through the uploaded files
foreach ($_FILES as $key => $value){
    $image_tmp = $value['tmp_name'];
    $image_type=$value['type'];
    $image = $value['name'];
    $image_file = "{$UPLOADDIR}{$image}";

 //check if there's existing file name
  if ($image  != 0){
echo 'File Already Exists!';
}

  else {
    // move the file to the permanent location

  if(move_uploaded_file($image_tmp,$image_file)){

// this is where the displaying part goes
    echo <<<HEREDOC

    <div style="float:left;margin-right:10px">
        <img src="$editedShear" alt="This is your image" height=200 width=200/></br>
    </div>

HEREDOC;

    }
    else{
        echo "<h1>image file upload failed, image too big after compression</h1>";
         }
        }
}}
 else{
  ?>

<?php
 }
?>
```

Comment: you have to use ajax request for that , means you have do the uploading using ajax, and on success you can show up the image

Comment: Are you getting error or seeing blank page after submit?

Comment: No, just a broken image. With the description of the image. That's what I am getting after the submit button

Comment: Side note, and I know the question is a few days old already, but you're using `$editedShear` as the image source, and don't have it declared anywhere.  Might help to turn on error reporting when you're debugging :)

Answer (score 0):

To do that you need to upload the image using some kind of ajax upload. if you don't know what is that, please read here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29. You can find some free solutions and examples online. Here I found a stack overflow question that might help you with links to such a solutions

[Ajax file upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2751795/ajax-file-upload)

Comment: Thanks for the info, but do you think it'll be more complex if I use Ajax File Upload? Honestly, I think using Ajax is a lot complex than what I am trying to do. But still, thank you for the info. I'm gonna use it for future use. :)

Answer (score 0):

Add an `iframe` after your form:

`<iframe name="resultFrame" width="500" height="300"></iframe>`

And add the `target="resultFrame"` attribute in your form like this:

```
<html>
    <body>    
        <form action="uploadFile.php" method="post"
enctype="multipart/form-data" target="resultFrame">
            <label for="file">Filename:</label>
            <input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>

        <iframe name="resultFrame" width="500" height="300"></iframe>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Still don't show any image. Thanks to your help BTW. :)

Comment: This code works fine but I think there's something wrong with my uploadFile.php file. I just don't know what it is. I will try to fix it. If you have any idea how. Keep me posted. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Upload your image in a folder which contains your php/html file,
and in img tag write the img name:

```
<img src="<?php echo $img;?>" width="400" height="600"/>
```

Comment: <img src="<?php echo $img;?>" width="400" height="600"/>

Answer (score 0):

```
/* i put image so that it has default

    <img id="blah" src="images/male.png" alt="your image" style="width:250px;height:200px;" />

/*put accept and its format so that you can only choose the image only

<input type='file' name="image"  onchange="readURL(this);" accept="image/gif,image/png,image/jpg,image/jpeg" />

/*changing the url of an image you can do it in jquery
function readURL(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function (e) {
                $('#blah')
                    .attr('src', e.target.result)
/*set the width and height of an image
                    .width(250)
                    .height(200);
            };

            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }
```

after that do your upload code

Answer (score 0):

What is the easiest way to upload images and display the uploaded images on same page?
page "index.php"

```html
<body>
<div id="body">
 <form action="upload.php" name="img_compress" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <input type="file" name="file" />
 <button type="submit" name="btn-upload">upload</button>
 </form>
    <br /><br />
    <?php
 if(isset($_GET['success']))
 {
  ?><br><br><br>
        
    <?php
 $sql="SELECT * FROM tbl_uploads ORDER BY id DESC";
 $result_set=mysql_query($sql);
 while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result_set))
    {
  ?>
     <img src="uploads/<?php echo $row['file'] ?>" width="100%" height="100%">
    <?php
}
 ?>
   
        <?php
 }
 else if(isset($_GET['fail']))
 {
  ?>
        <label>Problem While File Uploading !</label>
        <?php
 }
 else
 {
  ?>
        <label>Try to upload any files(PDF, DOC, EXE, VIDEO, MP3, ZIP,etc...)</label>
        <?php
 }
 ?>
</div>
</body>
```

code for upload "upload.php"

```html
<?php
include_once 'dbconfig.php';
if(isset($_POST['btn-upload']))
{    
     
 $file = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $file_loc = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
 $file_size = $_FILES['file']['size'];
 $file_type = $_FILES['file']['type'];
 $folder="uploads/";
 
 $new_size = $file_size/1024;  
 
 $new_file_name = strtolower($file);
 
 $final_file=str_replace(' ','-',$new_file_name);
 
 if(move_uploaded_file($file_loc,$folder.$final_file))
 {
  $sql="INSERT INTO tbl_uploads(file,type,size) VALUES('$final_file','$file_type','$new_size')";
  mysql_query($sql);
  ?>
  <script>
        window.location.href='index.php?success';
        </script>
  <?php
 }
 else
 {
  ?>
  <script>
  alert('error while uploading file');
        window.location.href='index.php?fail';
        </script>
  <?php
 }
}
?>
```

below one is fields for storing images
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xLIXC.jpg)

Comment: you should consider editing your code. Bcoz  your heading says "upload and display on the same page" while you are using 2 pages( upload.php and index.php ).